# Adding a new node to existing node cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

Starting from one host running Cassandra, I am trying to add a new node and form a cluster.

I update the seeds list on both hosts and after restarting both nodes, I do `nodetool status` and see both nodes forming a cluster. However, I am seeing some data loss issue. I am not seeing all the data that I added to a column family before I added the new node.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start a node with following settings in cassandra.yaml

   - `initial_token:`
   - `num_tokens:256`
   - `seed_list: host1`
2. Create a keyspace and a column family and enter some data
3. Start another node, exact same settings and host1 with the following settings changes on both `- seeds: host1, host2`
4. When I log in to cal from host2, I do not see all data.

Comment: Did you update the replication factor on your keyspace?

Comment: No, the replication factor is still set to 1. What is a good practice, should I set the replication factor to the number of nodes in my cluster ?

Comment: Updating the replication factor does not help. Still seeing the issue.

Comment: The idea with the replication factor, is that you could lose a machine and still have all of your data.  With 2 servers and a replication factor of 1, losing a machine means losing half of your data.  So with 2 servers it makes sense to go with a replication factor of 2.  But if you went to 3 nodes, staying with a RF of 2 would still allow you to get 100% of your data if you lost a node.

Comment: I agree, but even if I have replication factor as 1, and only a part of data resides on one host, when I do a select * from a node, I should still get all the data for all the nodes. My issue is that when I do a select * I do not see the full data.

Comment: I am having this exact same problem.  Did you determine a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Will suggest you to run a `nodetool cleanup` in both the nodes so that keys get distributed.

Comment: Does not work. Surprisingly when I decommission the newly added node, I can see all the data again from CQL in old host.

Answer (score 1):

Running:

```
nodetool cleanup
nodetool repair
nodetool rebuild
```

should solve the issue.

Comment: Tried this, still see the same issue. Anything else that I could try.

Comment: With replication factor 1, it will be written only on 1 node.

Comment: Right, but doing a select * should return data from all the hosts right ? I am not sure why select * is not returning the entire data.

Comment: @Nitin, you may need to use consistency of QUORUM or ALL if you are not already.

Comment: I tried a repair, but somehow it blocks forever (or at least what looks like forever) without doing anything (at least seemingly, since the process does nothing and no data gets transferred...) Would there be a reason for the repair not to work in that situation?